# Line crushed after adding the 2nd list to create excel file

Tags: java, excel

I want to insert two list in the same HSSFSheet I start by the first one and when I go to insert values of the second list the firstone is crushed

this is my method of generating excel file

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet spreadsheet = workbook.createSheet("employe db");
        HSSFRow row = spreadsheet.createRow(0);
        HSSFCell cell;

        cell = row.createCell(0);
        cell.setCellValue("Ref");
        cell = row.createCell(1);
        cell.setCellValue("Fournisseur");
        cell = row.createCell(2);
        cell.setCellValue("Produit");
        cell = row.createCell(3);
        cell.setCellValue("Quantité");
        cell = row.createCell(4);
        cell.setCellValue("Prix");
        cell = row.createCell(5);
        cell.setCellValue("Somme");
        cell = row.createCell(6);
        cell.setCellValue("Solde Avant");
        cell = row.createCell(7);
        cell.setCellValue("Après");
        cell = row.createCell(8);
        cell.setCellValue("Date");
        cell = row.createCell(9);
        cell.setCellValue("Description");
        //paiement//
        cell = row.createCell(14);
        cell.setCellValue("Libellé");
        cell = row.createCell(15);
        cell.setCellValue("Type");
        cell = row.createCell(16);
        cell.setCellValue("Montant");
        cell = row.createCell(17);
        cell.setCellValue("Date ");
        cell = row.createCell(18);
        cell.setCellValue("Echance");

        Iterator<AchatProduit> itr = list.iterator();
        int i = 1;
        while (itr.hasNext()) {
            AchatProduit emp = (AchatProduit) itr.next();
            row = spreadsheet.createRow(i);
            cell = row.createCell(0);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getPk_seq());
            cell = row.createCell(1);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getFournisseur().getNom() + " // " + emp.getFournisseur().getSociete());
            cell = row.createCell(2);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getProduit().getLibelle());
            cell = row.createCell(3);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getQuantite());
            cell = row.createCell(4);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getPrix());
            cell = row.createCell(5);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getSomme());
            cell = row.createCell(6);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getSoldeAvant());
            cell = row.createCell(7);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getSoldeApres());
            cell = row.createCell(8);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getStringDateAchat());
            cell = row.createCell(9);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getDescription());

            i++;
        }
        Iterator<CompteFournisseur> itr2 = listPaiement.iterator();
        int j = 1;
        while (itr2.hasNext()) {
            CompteFournisseur emp = (CompteFournisseur) itr2.next();
            row = spreadsheet.createRow(j);/// line that cauz problem
            cell = row.createCell(14);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getLibellePaiment());
            cell = row.createCell(15);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getTypePaiement());
            cell = row.createCell(16);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getMontant());
            cell = row.createCell(17);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getStringDatePaiement());
            cell = row.createCell(18);
            cell.setCellValue(emp.getStringDateEcheance());
            j++;
        }
        FileOutputStream out = null;
        try {
            String exepath = path;
            if (exepath.endsWith(".xls") || exepath.endsWith(".xlsx")) {
                out = new FileOutputStream(new File(exepath));
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Executed successfully");
            } else {
                String bufpath = exepath.concat(".xls");
                out = new FileOutputStream(new File(bufpath));
                workbook.write(out);
                out.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception aa) {
        }

    }
```

[image]

normaly the yellow area should have values also but when I call this row = spreadsheet.createRow(j); beacause j=1; so it crush the values of first iterator (it)

so there any way to insert values because I have two lists

thanks is advance

UPDATE

```
Iterator<CompteFournisseur> itr2 = listPaiement.iterator();
        int j = 1;
        while (itr2.hasNext()) {
            CompteFournisseur emp = (CompteFournisseur) itr2.next();
            row = spreadsheet.getRow(j);
            if (row == null) {
                row = spreadsheet.createRow(j);
                cell = row.createCell(14);
                cell.setCellValue(emp.getLibellePaiment());
                cell = row.createCell(15);
                cell.setCellValue(emp.getTypePaiement());
                cell = row.createCell(16);
                cell.setCellValue(emp.getMontant());
                cell = row.createCell(17);
                cell.setCellValue(emp.getStringDatePaiement());
                cell = row.createCell(18);
                cell.setCellValue(emp.getStringDateEcheance());
            } else {
                cell = row.createCell(14);
                cell.setCellValue(emp.getLibellePaiment());
                cell = row.createCell(15);
                cell.setCellValue(emp.getTypePaiement());
                cell = row.createCell(16);
                cell.setCellValue(emp.getMontant());
                cell = row.createCell(17);
                cell.setCellValue(emp.getStringDatePaiement());
                cell = row.createCell(18);
                cell.setCellValue(emp.getStringDateEcheance());
            }
            j++;
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean "crush"? overwrite?

Comment: it remove or delete the data that I inserted in the 1rst Iterator

Comment: first of all: don't ever do this: catch (Exception aa) {
        } how are you going to tell whether an exception was thrown, and, if so, which one? do you mean the new values are all written in the line in which you have written data during the first iteration?

Comment: there is a method named addMergedRegion of HSSFSheet to merge lines have you any idea about it ?

Comment: no, I don't. do you have an answer on what I asked?

Comment: yes about your question yes  exactly what I want to do

Comment: I'm not asking what you want, I 'm asking you to be more clear about what is happening now. also, did you check whether an exception is thrown?

Comment: I dont have any exception but the data that must be show in the yellow area is not showing

Comment: how did you verify that there is no Exception? debug? print statement? print of stacktrace? In your question you state that the results of the iteration are "crushed" by later iterations, implying that at one point in the flow, that data IS present in the xls file. How did you verify that?

Comment: see update thanks for helping I got the created row and I put data instead of create I new row that delete the previous data wich I added